# How can I autonomously dump/push the AP logs from the assortment of devices without logging into each?

Tags: wireless-networking, openvpn, logging, amazon-web-services, snort

I am running an `AWS OpenVPN EC2` server providing a VPN for mobile devices.

Additionally, I am managing an `OpenWRT` in my house, an ISP provided Linksys in another state, and a mid-grade `Cisco Aironet` in yet another state.

I have administrative rights to each Access Point (AP) but, not physical access, and would like to send the traffic from all AP's through Snort + Bro, also running in AWS.

1. How can I autonomously dump/push the AP logs from the assortment of devices without logging into each.
2. Am I overdoing this, or doing it wrong?